# Tomcat 7 Does not Run on Netbeans

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, ide

Tomcat Server 7 does not start through Netbeans 8.1 for some reason.

However, Tomcat webpage starts up on browser in localhost:8080. Saying congratulations you have successfully installed Tomcat!

Things I Have Tried:

1. Changed Port Number

   2. Changed server.xml
   3. Took off quotations in catalina.bat file:
2. :noJuliConfig  set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_CONFIG%
3. :noJuliManager  set  JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_MANAGER%
4. Unticked IDE Proxy Settings

The annoying thing is. Tomcat can run through Netbeans on my home network. When I come to university or use another network. I try to start Tomcat, but the message I get after a while through Netbeans is "Starting of Tomcat failed". Is this a firewall setting perhaps?

I am using apache_tomcat version 7.0.70 and have tried Netbeans 8.2 and other Tomcat versions. Any help would be really appreciated.

I am using a MacBook Pro, so had to install Tomcat independently. As does not come with Netbeans EE bundle on MAC.

Comment: Look into the log (`catalina.out` usually) for full error message.

Comment: Had a look, see no error message. Last line says: Server startup in 3328 ms